# Express Validator to validate DateTime

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, express

I want to validate DateTime like this code below

```
{
    "data": {
        "start": "2018-05-12 08:00:00"
    }
}
```

How to combine isISO8601() and match(regex) to validate date & time in start

```
body('*.start')
  .exists()
  .not()
  .isEmpty()
  .withMessage('start cannot be empty')
  .isISO8601('yyyy-mm-dd')
  .matches('^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$')
  .withMessage('start must be in correct format yyyy:mm:dd hh:mm:ss'),
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately having datetime validation is currently unavailable with `express-validator`.

Meanwhile you can go for a pure regex, which will be,

```
.matches('/^([\+-]?\d{4}(?!\d{2}\b))((-?)((0[1-9]|1[0-2])(\3([12]\d|0[1-9]|3[01]))?|W([0-4]\d|5[0-2])(-?[1-7])?|(00[1-9]|0[1-9]\d|[12]\d{2}|3([0-5]\d|6[1-6])))([T\s]((([01]\d|2[0-3])((:?)[0-5]\d)?|24\:?00)([\.,]\d+(?!:))?)?(\17[0-5]\d([\.,]\d+)?)?([zZ]|([\+-])([01]\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\d)?)?)?)?$/)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: getting error SyntaxError: Octal escape sequences are not allowed in strict mode.

Answer (score 13):

The express-validator documentation does it like so now:
`check('date-of-birth').isISO8601().toDate(),`
source:
[Validation Chain API v6 Example](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/6.15.0/validation-chain-api)
[Validation Chain API v7](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/api/validation-chain)

Comment: How to use this in schema? I can't find anything in the docs...

Answer (score 4):

To Validate this format= "2022-09-09T00:00:00" as string from HTML form

```
check('holiday.day').isISO8601().toDate()
            .withMessage("Invalid day received")
```

Answer (score 2):

As of 2021 this can be done by using [isISO8601(str)](https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js) from validator library (which express-validator uses behind the scene). More info on [ISO8601 here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)
Hope this helps ;-)